# Downloaded file is corrupt which is not

Tags: c#, .net, excel, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to download a file through webapi, which works perfectly, except for Excel.
The excel file is downloaded successfully, and when I open the same it gives me a "File is corrupt" error. However, it is not corrupt.

When I search on the Internet it is asking me to follow these:

1. Open Excel .
2. Click on File > Options.
3. Select Trust Center > Trust center settings.
4. Select Protected view.
5. Uncheck all the options under Protected View > OK.
6. Restart Excel and try to open Excel documents.

After changing this setting, I can open the downloaded file without any problem.

**I can understand it is client side thing but I don't want to do the same on every single machine. Because, With my understanding on protection is that if you download any file, it will still open but it will be in a protected mode.**

**But in my case it is showing as "File is Corrupt", which is a wrong explanation for end-user.**

I am sure there are many website out there where you can download from and it work as expected i.e. you can still open but in a protected mode.

Please note: File is uploaded from Excel 2013 and viewed from Excel 2010.

Here is the download code that I am currently using:

```
private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            StreamContent streamContent = null;

            if (Content == null)
            {
                streamContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(MapPath(LocalPath)));
            }
            else
            {
                streamContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Content));
            }

            response.Content = streamContent;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = DownloadFileName,
            };

            return response;
        }
```

> The content type is set as:
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: Ignoring the whole upload/download steps, what happens if you stick the file on a thumb drive and try to load it on the computer with Excel 2010?  Is it a case of compatibility going from 2013 --> 2010?

Comment: The file is loading if it is read from drive

Comment: Are you saying that Excel 2010 can open an Excel 2013 file? What happens of you unzip the xlsx and compare the corrupt downloaded file and the working thumb drive file? Make sure you download it, to disk, not open it directly in Excel when comparing these.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Protected Mode today with files downloaded from the Internet.  It turned out that the underlying cause was that the user had lost their permissions to %TEMP% (normally c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp).  MS Office puts the file in a sandbox in that folder to help protect you.

You can verify the location of %TEMP% by running

```
echo %TEMP%
```

on the command line for that user.

1. Browse to the folder using Windows Explorer
2. Right click on the Temp folder
3. Go to the Permissions tab
4. Grant the current user Full Control.